# how come the position static on my element doesnt position relative to the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that has `position: relative` assigned to it, inside this div I have an anchor tag that has `position: fixed` assigned to it. Instead of the `<a>` being positioned relative to its parent div it positions itself to the body. Can anyone explain how I can resolve this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DWMTn/

**CSS**

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}

.main {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `position:fixed` is relative to the viewport so you are unable to achieve what you want with css alone.  If you want to keep the `btn` fixed to the `main` container then you are going to need to use a absolute positioning with a little bit of javascript too.

In this example I have used the jQuery library to move the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/DWMTn/7/

```
var main = $('.main:eq(0)'); //would be better to use an id here
var button = $('.btn:eq(0)'); //would be better to use an id here
var max = main.height() - button.height();

button.css('bottom', 'auto'); //removes the original bottom positioning

function moveButton() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - button.height();
    if (top > max) {
        top = max;
    }

    button.css('top', top + 'px');
}

moveButton();

$(window).scroll(function() { moveButton(); });
$(window).resize(function() { moveButton(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed position element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of the  being positioned relative to its parent div it positions itself to the body.

Not body, but viewport – http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning:

> *“Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport.”*

Works as designed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear on how you want this layout to behave, but I'd bet there are CSS ways to fix it. If you wanted it to stay in the bottom right corner:

```
.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 200px; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You can also use margins to further position your element. For example, if you want it centered:

```
.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: -50px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```